# Android ArrayList Issue

Tags: android

I have generated ArrayList from class like

```
coinArrayList=  ShowDash.getCoins();
```

and When I check the output of this Array like

```
Log.d("coinArrayList", "" + String.valueOf(coinArrayList) );
```

I get an output like

```
D/coinArrayList: [{CoinName=COIN1, CoinBal=0.0, CoinPrice=8919.52}, {CoinName=COIN2, CoinBal=0.0, CoinPrice=101200.0}, {CoinName=COIN3, CoinBal=0.0, CoinPrice=112603.0}, {CoinName=COIN4, CoinBal=0.0, CoinPrice=226263.0}
```

Now I need first value CoinName from this ArrayList so I wrote

```
Log.d("coinArrayList", "" + String.valueOf(coinArrayList.get(0).getCoinName()));
```

Here I always get null value.  Why I don't know.

Comment: Why String.valueOf() ? when coinArrayList.get(0).getCoinName() is returning a string.

Comment: Okay but still without String.valueOf() it returns null value.

Comment: welcome to SO community; how did you managed to log the array list like you did.. I guess you should have got something that refers to a reference like like `@7a6d005...` isn't it?

Comment: show more information so we can help!